# How can I select items from a list by DateTime

Tags: c#, list, datetime

I have a a list of these objects:

```
public class Event
{
        public int ID;
        public DateTime DateBegin;
        public DateTime DateEnd;
        public DateTime TimeBegin;
        public int Duration;
        public string Name;
        public string Description;

        public Event()
        {

        }
}
```

Here is some sample `ID`s and `DateBegin` Properties:

```
1968    2014-11-23 00:00:00.000
1924    2014-12-02 00:00:00.000
1925    2014-12-04 00:00:00.000
1664    2014-12-05 00:00:00.000
1412    2014-12-06 00:00:00.000
1976    2014-12-06 00:00:00.000
1413    2014-12-07 00:00:00.000
1414    2014-12-07 00:00:00.000
1665    2014-12-07 00:00:00.000
1952    2014-12-07 00:00:00.000
1972    2014-12-07 00:00:00.000
1977    2014-12-07 00:00:00.000
1978    2014-12-07 00:00:00.000
```

How can I cycle through this list so that each day that has an event displayes all events for that day.

**Example using above data:**

- 11/23/14

  - 1968
- 12/02/14

  - 1924
- 12/04/14

  - 1925
- 12/05/14

  - 1664
- 12/06/14

  - 1412
  - 1976
- ...

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Do you have any code that you've attempted already?

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following:

```
var results = events.GroupBy(x=>x.DateBegin)
                    .Select(x=> new { Date = x.Key, Ids = x.Select(y=>y.ID) });
```

I suppose that `events` is a collection with all the events objects you have. Initially you groub by your events based on their DateBegin and then you declare an anonymous type inside the `Select` method, with two properties, the Date and the Ids of the events in this day.